# Disabling keys in browser?

Tags: cross-browser, browser

I'm getting started on a module for my website, looking for a method that extends flash (for example, something I can do with JavaScript) to disable keyboard commands.  For example, I'd like to be able to disable the F1 key, so that it doesn't open up the support tab in Chrome.  I looked into access keys, but they don't seem to be a good solution.  If anyone has info on how this may be possible, even which language I should be looking into, or even if they have attempted it and simply found it to be impossible, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if other browsers then Chrome works for you, but have you tried some of these solutions?

[1] [How to disable default Help function of browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9019278/how-to-disable-default-help-function-of-browsers)

[2] [Disable F1-Help key in browser and set your own help file or link or pages etc...](http://blogfornet.com/2013/05/disable-f1-help-key-in-browser-and-set-your-own-help-file-or-link-or-pages-etc/)

[3] [How to Disable Function keys using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13678847/how-to-disable-function-keys-using-javascript)

Comment: Actually, no, I haven't seen these.  Of course, I did mean programmatically.  So, I think these might work.  Thank you very much.  This info is very useful.

Comment: Glad that helped!
Actually, I was looking for disabling at all the F1 key in the Chrome(ium) browser and found your question.
Still though I found no solution without using it in a specific web page.

Comment: Well, actually, you know, I was trying to do it programmatically for a service, as a service host.  So, when a user comes to my webpage and goes full-screen, they don't have these keys disrupting the full-screen view.  But; `case 112 : // 'F1'
document.onhelp = function() {return(false);}
window.onhelp = function() {return(false);}
NewEntry();
break;`