# How to stop users to make changes in values by using Inspect Element / Developer Tool or by pressing F12?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, browser

How to stop users to make changes in values by using Inspect Element / Developer Tool or by pressing F12?
Presently users are able to make changes in values. I want to stop it.
Is there any idea with out disabling keys?

Comment: If it is a form submit or something like that, you could probably validate at server side (i.e., if you have one). If not you wont be able to prevent it from a good computer user. To prevent from newbies and freshers, you could prevent key press by checking key code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Disable Function keys using Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13678847/how-to-disable-function-keys-using-javascript)

Comment: This is not about the disabling the Function keys, It is about stop changes in values.

Answer (score 2):

You can not prevent that, because it happens on the users computers, and you have no control over those (usually).

Comment: I saw few sites, that do it...facebook for example

Comment: They only make it harder, not impossible - you can for example add a handler for right clicks that prevents the context menu from opening. But you cannot prevent a user from opening firebug and using its "select"-tool.

Comment: @ArsenMkrt Facebook doesn't do that, you can easily change something on FB via the developer tools.

Comment: some sites just dump some copyright message in that window... I agree, that it just makes harder... but however not sure how they do it

Comment: but i saw in one website, I pressed F12, I can see the HTML source code , but i was unable to make changes.

Comment: Well, which website?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the url