# How to disable F1 key?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, c#-4.0

I want to disable <kbd>F1</kbd> key. I tried to do it, but it's not working in Chrome.

```
document.onhelp=function() {return false;};
window.onhelp=function() {return false;};
```

Comment: Duplicated question: solution here: how to disable default help function of browsers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9019278/how-to-disable-default-help-function-of-browsers

Answer (score 4):

Use `preventDefault` :

```
window.addEventListener("keydown",function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 112) { 
        e.preventDefault();
    }
})
```

This is brief, however, To have something more compatible with browsers , [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9019462/747579) .

Answer (score -2):

Nice worked thank , F11 and F6 also disabled. "event.preventDefault();" function works.